# Visual C#: Compile with Runtime DLLs

Tags: c#, runtime

I'm trying to compile my program in Visual C#. However, the machine I need it to run on (well, I need it to be able to run on any Windows Machine, at least Windows XP) does not have the .NET DLLs installed. I'm new to this, so how can I compile my Visual C# program with the runtime DLLs so that it will run on other machines?

Comment: You **cannot** - at least not easily. You need to have the .NET framework installed on all machines that want to run your app. Period. It's just like a service pack, after all - get over it - install it.

Comment: You seem very resistant to installing the framework.  Any particular reason?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't install the .NET framework on the target machines? It is freely available from Microsoft and would most likely be installed on most machines already.

Comment: Windows XP SP2 comes with the .NET Framework 2.0.  So it sounds like you needn't worry.  (Vista, Windows7 of course come with more advanced versions, too)

Comment: No I just found it surprising that in order to run a simple program I've made that I need this installed. I'm making this application for someone else and they asked if I could compile it as I've described. If it's easier to just install the framework, however, I will speak with them about this.

Comment: Also, I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2010, which comes with the new .NET Framework 4.0. Can I compile for a lower version?

Comment: @rar: If you'd written it in Java, Python, Perl or Ruby, you still would have need to install the runtime. Some of those languages can be recompiled into native machine code, but that's usually via 3rd party tools, not a basic capability of the standard toolset. There might also be .NET-to-assembly tools, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @rar: Yes, there should be a way to target other versions of .NET. From what I recall, it's somewhere in the Project Settings, I don't know VS 2010, so I can't tell you which tab it's on, but previously, I think it was on the Compiler tab. You could choose which .NET version to compile for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Click-Once deployment, [you can set a setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in the installer that the installer should install the .NET framework before running. If that's not an option (such as target machine has slow/no internet connection) you can install the [redistributable version of .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 5):

There is no way. You need .NET runtime installed prior running any .NET application.

Comment: Well I wish I would have known that before I made my program using Visual Studio...

Comment: That is not a Visual Studio limitation, its a C# one. If you use Visual Studio to write a C++ program, you could then xcopy deploy it to most windows machines, since they'll have the standard C++ libs

Comment: @rar, you can develop an unmanaged C++ application with Visual Studio that targets XP.  Just make sure the project defines the WINVER variable to be NTDDI_WINXP (if you don't want to rely on any service packs being installed.)  Change the runtime library in the compiler settings to /MT (so that the C runtime libraries are compiled in) and don't use ATL/MFC/Etc unless you can also compile them in.

Comment: Problem is I've already coded it all in Visual C#, this would be a big task to change over.

Comment: @rar: As long it is possible to install .NET on the target machine, you have nothing to worry about. See my answer about using ClickOnce to detect dependencies on .NET, or installing a pre-compiled redistributable version of .NET.

Comment: There should'nt be any problem with including the redistributable with your application. A lot of commercial applications install .NET Framework if it's not already in the target machine.
There are no reasons for not installing the framework. All virtual machines work like that: java, php, phyton ...

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  .Net programs can only run if the .Net framework / CLR is installed on the target machine.  There is no pure XCOPY deployment story for this scenario.